# Composite key from two objects of the same type

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have a simple `Employee` class

```
class Employee
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and another class `Transaction` which contains two employees:

```
class Transaction
{
    public virtual Employee Registrant { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

Why can't I make `Transaction` have a composite key, consisting of the Ids of both employees. I do that like this:

`modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().HasKey(t => new { t.Registrant.Id, t.Recipient.Id });`

and Visual Studio will tell me:

> Duplicate anonymous type property name 'Id'

Comment: Yes... It is kind of hard to have type (anonymous or not) with 2 fields with the same name... Why can't you have different names like `new {Id1= .., Id2 = ...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your `Transaction` model like this:

```
class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string RegistrantId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string RecipientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(Name = "RegistrantId")]
    public virtual Employee Registrant { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(Name = "RecipientId")]
    public virtual Employee Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

EF is only so good at guessing what to do in unusual circumstances. In this case, adding the explicit properties for the two IDs should help it arrive at the right mapping to SQL.

You may not need all of the attributes I added, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit by having them there.

You shouldn't need this anymore:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().HasKey(t => new { t.Registrant.Id, t.Recipient.Id });
```

Here's a good resource you can refer to for future problems:

[Entity Framework Code First Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591583#relationships)

Comment: If I add a surrogate key and update the database, entity-framework will create [these names automatically](http://i.imgur.com/cTsaJjW.png). So why do I need 2 additional fields? It seems redundant to me.

Comment: @transporter_room_3 What surrogate key are you adding? I don't understand the comment.  You haven't revealed what your desired entity-relationship model is, so I'm not going to try to guess it...

Comment: Nevermind me, this is the correct answer. I was just confusing myself.

Answer (score 3):

When you write new { t.Registrant.Id, t.Recipient.Id } compiler try to generate anonymous type with fields Id and Id because he use names of properties Registrant.Id and Recipient.Id. Type can't contains multiple properties with the same name and compiler generate error. To avoid this you should instruct compiler to use another names:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().HasKey(t => new { RegistrantiId = t.Registrant.Id, RecipientId = t.Recipient.Id });
```